# PeopleSoft Page Development

Tags: duplicates, components, key, peoplesoft

I am very new to PS development. I am creating a very simple component with single effective dated table described here. I have creaed a page where the field CODE is at level 0 and remainder of the fields are in a scroll at level 1. The component search record is MyTable.

### MyTable

CODE         -- KEY 1, Searchable = Y.
DESCRIPTION
EFFDT        -- KEY 2, Searchable = N.
EFF_STATUS

To add a new record, I use the 'Add New Value' tab on the Search page which brings me to the page I created to enter decription, effdt, and status. I enter description and leave the defaults for the effective date (1/1/1901) and status (A). When I hit save, I get error message "Data being added conflicts with existing data. (18,2) When adding a new item to the database, the system found a conflicting item already exists... " whenver I am creating a new code. It happens even when MyTable is emply and there are no rows in it.

The only way I can save if I change the effdate to something other than 1/1/1901. But then when I save, it saved two rows. One with effdt of 1/1/1901 and a second one with effdat I am entered.

I have read peoplebooks about level processing and parent/cihld relationship when creating pages and scrolls. What I am not understanding properly.